# Does grid-area in CSS have two meanings?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is grid-area used with grid-template-areas, like the example below

```
               grid-template-areas: "head head"
                   "nav  main"
                   "nav  foot";


   
             #page > header {
             grid-area: head;
             background-color: #8ca0ff;
                }
```

And also as a shorthand for grid-row-start, grid-column-start, grid-row-end, grid-column-end?

Comment: It’s fundamentally the same meaning - where to put the item. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element you can better understand

[image]

It's always the shorthand of the properties you mentioned. Now if you check [the syntax of such properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-start#values) you will notice that it can take different values.

The named areas belong to `<cutom-indent>`

Related questions for more detail:

[CSS grid and specifying multiple areas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56238923/8620333)

[CSS Grid: grid-row/column-start/end VS grid-area + grid-template-area](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55213061/8620333)